# Joomla - Use index.php instead of "/" as homepage

Tags: joomla

Let:

- test.tld = domain
- test.tld/index.php = my Joomla home page
- test.tld/ = a pre-release page (index.html) that isn't Joomla

Now Joomla always wants to go to test.tld/ as homepage so I basically get lost (because it isn't Joomla)

How to set Joomla so that the Menu to homepage is "test.tld/index.php" not assume I want "test.tld/" ?

I already tried making a dummy homepage on an invisible menu so that the "home" on the navigation isn't really a "home"

Is there no better way? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue in two ways:

1. **Recommended:** Your web-server default index is set to `index.html` file. You can change that based on your web-server (Apache, Nginx, whatever).
2. **NOT Recommended:** You can disable Rewrite URLs feature in `Global Configuration` of your site, this will show index.php on every page.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but,

For #1, we want the index.html to be the index file, it is the non-joomla "under construction" page

#2 - rewrite is off, by default, and it is still off

What I want is Joomla not linking to "/" anywhere but instead use the whole url of the home (index.php/home or something)

Is this not possible as of now?

Comment: If you want to have "underconstruction" just set your site to offline and put whatever you want to say in the offline page. It's nice to add   maybe a sign up form for notification when the site goes live and maybe basic contact information.

Comment: @Elin thanks for the suggestion, but my question wasn't that, I was asking if there's such feature as "don't assume I like '/' url"; is there really none of it?

Comment: You're making it more complicated than you need to. Joomla has a built in way to have a substitute page: offline.php in the root of your template folder.  Inside that you can do whatever you want, redirect etc.  You could probably write a custom sef plugin to do what you want, but why not use the api instead of fighting it?