# How to get rid of "Index of /" when I visit my test site? [WordPress]

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, hosting

When I visit my site I see something like this:

## **Index of /**

- wordpress/

---

This is what file directory looks like: 
[image]

---

.htaccess file:

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
    enter code here
```

---

What do I need to do so that when I visit example.com and I see the my wordpress site without the **Index of /** and list of pages?

Comment: `.htcaccess` file? that's not what apache looks for. it's `.htaccess`. and only when allowed to do si, via `allowoverrides`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joomla - Use index.php instead of "/" as homepage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259815/joomla-use-index-php-instead-of-as-homepage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have any index.php file in your public_html. When you get the directory listing, it is because there is not file inside that directory which matches the `DirectoryIndex` option. A typically WordPress website will include an index.php, so once you place the WordPress files there, that should go away. You could use `Options -Indexes` in the .htaccess file to hide that page, but that would give you a 403 error, and still not show your contents, so moving the content into the correct location is what you really want to do.

It appears that you may have placed your files into the directory you named "wordpress". If that is the case, try visiting http://example.com/wordpress/. If that is not what you were wanting, then just move the contents of "wordpress" into the public_html/ directory.